# Exceptions when reading tutorial CSV file in the Cloudera VM

Tags: python, csv, hadoop, pyspark, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm trying to do a Spark tutorial that comes with the Cloudera Virtual Machine. But even though I'm using the correct line-ending encoding, I can not execute the scripts, because I get tons of errors. 
The tutorial is part of the Coursera [Introduction to Big Data Analytics](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bigdata-analytics/) course. The assignment [can be found here](http://matthias-heise.eu/programming_assignment_%20dataframe.pdf).

So here's what I did. Install the IPython shell (if not yet done):

```
sudo easy_install ipython==1.2.1
```

Open/Start the shell (either with 1.2.0 or 1.4.0):

```
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0
```

Set the line-endings to windows style. This is because the file is in windows-encoding and it's said in the course to do so. If you don't do this, you'll get other errors.

```
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set('textinputformat.record.delimiter','\r\n')
```

Trying to load the CSV file:

```
yelp_df = sqlCtx.load(source='com.databricks.spark.csv',header = 'true',inferSchema = 'true',path = 'file:///usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv')
```

But getting a very long list of errors, which starts like this:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o23.load.: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to instantiate 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient at 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:472)
```

The full error message [can be seen here](http://matthias-heise.eu/error_programming_assignment_%20dataframe.txt). And this is the /etc/hive/conf/hive-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>

  <!-- Hive Configuration can either be stored in this file or in the hadoop configuration files  -->
  <!-- that are implied by Hadoop setup variables.                                                -->
  <!-- Aside from Hadoop setup variables - this file is provided as a convenience so that Hive    -->
  <!-- users do not have to edit hadoop configuration files (that may be managed as a centralized -->
  <!-- resource).                                                                                 -->

  <!-- Hive Execution Parameters -->

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
    <value>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
    <description>JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
    <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
    <description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
    <value>hive</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
    <value>cloudera</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
    <value>/usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hwi-0.8.1-cdh4.0.0.jar</value>
    <description>This is the WAR file with the jsp content for Hive Web Interface</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://127.0.0.1:9083</value>
    <description>IP address (or fully-qualified domain name) and port of the metastore host</description>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Any help or idea how to solve that? I guess it's a pretty common error. But I couldn't find any solution, yet.

One more thing: is there a way to dump such long error messages into a separate log-file?

Comment: It seems like you are working in unix environment, why are you setting the line-endings to windows style? Can you try again without issuing this command? Also - can you please add the last part of the error you get?

Comment: Which version of Cloudera VM are you using?

Comment: Because the file is in Windows encoding and the tutorial says so. btw: the Cloudera QuickStart VM is CDH 5.7

Comment: please send a link to the tutorial you are referring, I hope to find some time to try it myself and understand the problem...

Comment: It's from the Coursera Introduction to [Big Data Analytics course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bigdata-analytics/). I've uploaded the description of the [assignment here](http://matthias-heise.eu/programming_assignment_%20dataframe.pdf). Remark: It's in the lessons slide that one need to use the Windows line breaks.

Comment: I didn't find ipython in the vm. Did you install it yourself? Is it part of other tutorial?

Comment: seems to me a problem with hive configuration, which is used by spark SQL Context. Would you add more logs  to know what is going on? and if possible your hive-site.xml used by spark?

Comment: I've updated the original post with all information about the error, hive-site.xml and how to install IPython into the Cloudera Quickstart VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of the discussion:
Executing the following command solved the issue:

```
sudo cp /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml /usr/lib/spark/conf/
```

see https://www.coursera.org/learn/bigdata-analytics/supplement/tyH3p/setup-pyspark-for-dataframes for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there are two problems. First, the hive-metastore was offline in some occasions. And second, the schema can not be inferred. Therefore I created a schema manually and added it as an argument when loading the CSV file. Anyway, I would love to understand if this works somehow with schemaInfer=true.

Here's my version with the manually defined schema. So, make sure the hive is started:

```
sudo service hive-metastore restart
```

Then, have a look into the first part of the CSV file to understand it's structure. I used this command line:

```
head /usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv
```

Now, open the python shell. See the original posting for how to do that. Then define the schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
schema = StructType([
    StructField("business_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("cool", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("date", StringType(), True),
    StructField("funny", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("stars", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("text", StringType(), True),
    StructField("type", StringType(), True),
    StructField("useful", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("user_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("full_address", StringType(), True),
    StructField("latitude", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("longitude", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("neighborhood", StringType(), True),
    StructField("open", StringType(), True),
    StructField("review_count", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("state", StringType(), True)])
```

Then load the CSV file by specifying the schema. Note that there is no need to set the windows line endings:

```
yelp_df = sqlCtx.load(source='com.databricks.spark.csv',
header = 'true',
schema = schema,
path = 'file:///usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv')
```

The the result by any method executed on the dataset. I tried getting the count, which worked perfectly.

```
yelp_df.count()
```

Thanks to the help of @yaron we could figure out how to load the CSV with inferSchema. First, you must setup the hive-metastore correctly:

```
sudo cp /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml /usr/lib/spark/conf/
```

Then, start the Python shell and DO NOT change the line endings to Windows encoding. Keep in mind that changing that is persistent (session invariant). So, if you changed it to Windows style before, you need to reset it it '\n'. Then load the CSV file with inferSchema set to true:

```
yelp_df = sqlCtx.load(source='com.databricks.spark.csv',
header = 'true',
inferSchema = 'true',
path = 'file:///usr/lib/hue/apps/search/examples/collections/solr_configs_yelp_demo/index_data.csv')
```

Comment: did you follow the instructions in in https://www.coursera.org/learn/bigdata-analytics/supplement/tyH3p/setup-pyspark-for-dataframes
and executed the following command:  sudo cp /etc/hive/conf.dist/hive-site.xml /usr/lib/spark/conf/  ?

Comment: Nope, Haven't seen that. They should have put that directly into the assignment. I will check that out and let you know.

Comment: @Yaron: thanks for the hint. it worked! just keep the unix line endings.

Comment: Great :) I've summary the solution in my answer below :)